# HTML forms - Multiple outputs from one input?

Tags: html, forms, input, output

Still a beginner so treat me gently.

I'm building an html "app" that takes days you are off-home as input and calculates multiple outputs such as: Pack: **5** shirts, **5** underwears, **3** pairs of socks..

```
<form oninput="x.value=(d.value).toFixed(0)">

<p>I'm going to be off-home for <input type="number" id="d" value=""> days. </p>

<p>I'll pack:</p><output id="result" name="x" for="d">X</output> <p>shirts.</p>
<output id="result" name="x" for="d">X</output> <p>underwears.</p>

</form>
```

At the moment I manage to get one output working, but if I add the second output, it won't work. I have read the form/input/output documentary - it didn't open for me.

Question:

**How can I print multiple outputs from one input?**

and

**how can I calculate different values for the output?**

(For example input values is 5, and I want the number of socks to be (5/2).toFixed(0)

I would prefer a HTML-only solution, but if javascript is needed, help me to get going.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to break it to you, but you're already using JavaScript :)

```
oninput="x.value=(d.value).toFixed(0)"
```

You also might want to reconsider using the "output" tag since it's not supported in IE:
[Output tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp)

HTML is used to define the structure of the document, so you'll have to use JavaScript (or equivalent) to get the functionality you want.

Comment: Totally fine! Thanks. I'll dig to to. :)